# react re-renders <video> element on playback when setting state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following code:

```js
function Player({
  videlEl,
  onTimeUpdate = () => {},
}: {
  videlEl: React.RefObject<HTMLVideoElement>;
  onTimeUpdate: () => void;
}) {
  const { file } = useVideoCreateStore();

  if (!file) return null;

  return (
    <video
      ref={videlEl}
      src={URL.createObjectURL(file)}
      controls
      onTimeUpdate={onTimeUpdate}
    />
  );
}

const PlayerMemo = memo(Player);

export default function VideoEdit({ video }: VideoEditProps) {
  const id = video.id;
  const videoHeight = video.height;
  const videoWidth = video.width;

  const [playTime, setPlayTime] = useState(0);

  const videoEl = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="relative border rounded-sm">
        <PlayerMemo
          videlEl={videoEl}
          onTimeUpdate={() => {
            const time = videoEl.current?.currentTime;

            console.log(videoEl);
            if (!time) {
              return;
            }

            setPlayTime(time);

            console.log(videoEl.current?.currentTime);
          }}
        />
      </div>
      <Button
        onClick={() => {
          capture2();
        }}
      >
        Capture
      </Button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Because of the `setState` in the `onTimeUpdate` function, the component re-renders the `<video>` on playback, and the video restarts again.

I've tried passing in a `useRef` as well as `React.memo` (see code), but nothing is stopping the re-render from happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure which props are changing, but I had to specifically add a custom checker in the `memo` function:

```
const PlayerMemo = memo(Player, (prev, next) => {
  return prev.video.id === next.video.id;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On each render new `onTimeUpdate` callback is created. Functions are compared by reference and it gets a new one on each render. You can use `useCallback` there. It does not prevent recreating of the callback among the renders, but it keeps one of the references to it until one of the dependencies change.

```
onTimeUpdate={useCallback(cb_here, dependencies_here)}
```

With your `ref` implementation, dependencies could be just an empty array

```
onTimeUpdate={useCallback(cb_here, [])}
```

Comment: tried this, didn't work, the re-render still happens, this `onTimeUpdate` is on the parent or inside the `Player` component?

Comment: @PGT prop to PlayerMemo. It is the one that uses React.memo